# Is there any way to hide/remove Stage field from standard Detail Page of Opportunity object?

Tags: opportunity, detail-page

Is there any way to hide/remove Stage field from standard Detail Page of Opportunity object?

I want Stage to be changed automatically and not manually by user.

I tried to edit Field Accessibility, but I had no luck. It said, it should be visible due to Page Layout. And on Page Layout I can't uncheck required checkbox.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot since it is set visible by Salesforce, if possible rename it to probability or some other label that makes more sense to your org

Comment: Actually, I want to get rid of Probability field too :-)

Comment: you cannot remove both the fields from the page. You can take JS route but there is no guarantee when SF will stop supporting or change its policies on JS hack.

Comment: Taking a step back, why would you even want to do this? If you are removing both the Stage and Probability you are most likely repurposing the Opportunity for something it was never meant to be used as.

Comment: another approach would be VF page using `apex:detail` plus jQuery to apply css `display:none` to the form element represented by StageName.

Comment: @techbusinessman, yes, you are right. But Opportunity object has been used for ages and now it is decided to work with it in this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You can't alter the behavior of this field, because it is involved in various system functions (forecasting, setting the default probability and forecast category, etc). Most standard objects won't allow some field or another to be removed. The most typical example is the Name field (Account Name, Contact Name, etc), but other fields, such as Close Date and Stage also can't be removed or even locked down because they are involved in integrated functions, such as forecasting, lead conversion, etc. These fields are usually documented in the Help & Training information under that object.

Comment: I assume, I can override Detail Page with my own Visualforce page, where I can not to put Stage field. Am I right?

Comment: It's not an option really, as it would take a lot of time to create that page and maintaining it will be a nightmare

Comment: @Chiz Not just a VF page. You're talking about writing validation rules to make sure people don't use/update it by API-based tools, import wizards, and such, and then coding your VF pages to use various defaults, etc. Not saying it *can't* be done, but I think you'd rather find useful things to with your time, like eating, breathing, and sleeping.